# Nixos X11 header files not found

Tags: nixos

When trying to build suckless/surf and suckless/st from source on NixOs, make cannot find X11 header files, e.g. `X11/X.h` and `X11/Xatom.h`. I do have `Xlib` installed. I also vaguely remember nixos put libraries in an interesting place, and I have seen people suggesting putting some paths to `C_INCLUDE` variable. Feels like I'm almost there, what's missing?

**Update:** adding `/home/username/.nix-profile/include` solved the problem for `X.h` and `Xatom.h`, but now it's complaining about `X11/extensions/render.h` I installed `libXrender` but it doesn't show up. Where do I find it?

Comment: Did you ever find out where to find `X11/extensions/render.h`? I'm having the same issue---I'm trying to install the haskell X11-xft package, which depends in libXrender, which in turn depends on `X11/extensions/render.h`.

EDIT: I realized that it comes from `xorg.renderproto`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

surf and st are already packaged ([here](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/applications/networking/browsers/surf/default.nix) and [here](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/applications/misc/st/default.nix)) in nixpkgs

one of the things i love nix is a possibility to override **any** step in build process, which also means you can change source of the code (eg: `src` attribute).

just for an example lets say you cloned surf into `/path/to/surf`. a `default.nix` file which would override `src`, but used all the other build steps would be:

```
{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {}
}:

pkgs.surf.overrideDerivation (old: {
  src = /path/to/surf;
})
```

above you would build using `nix-build default.nix`

another way which you can also use is to use `nix-shell`. `nix-shell` is a tool that would drop you into nix environment, not running nix build steps, but all dependencies (buildInputs, propagatedBuildInputs) will be available for you. for more about `nix-shell` you can read [here](http://nixos.org/nix/manual/#sec-nix-shell).

to use `nix-shell` you can do:

```
% cd /path/where/above/mentioned/default.nix/is
% nix-shell
```

or you can work on clone of nixpkgs

```
% cd /path/to/nixpkgs
... here edit file pkgs/applications/misc/st/default.nix
% nix-build -A st    # to build st
% nix-shell -A st    # to enter development environment
```

i hope above helps.

Comment: Thanks! The first option appears to work the best, `nix-shell` doesn't seem to see runtime libraries. To follow up, nix-build builds the project, but how does one install it system-wide? I couldn't find pointers from the manual.

Comment: Figured out -- `nix-env -f default.nix -i`

Comment: you can even put it in ``~/.nixpkgs/config.nix`` and then use ``nix-env -i surf``. or if you are on NixOS then you can add overrides in ``nixpkgs.config.packageOverrides``.